# Can't login to openfire administrator console. It always told me "make sure your username and password are correct"

Tags: openfire

I am new to OpenFire.

I have an OpenFire server on CentOS, but I'm unable to login to the admin console.

When I try, it always displays the following message:

"Make sure your username and password are correct and that you're an admin or moderator."

So far, I have tried the following:

1. Open openfire.xml
2. Reset setup by setting the setup parameter to 'false'
3. Restarting the OpenFire server
4. Accessing the admin console via browser
5. Select a DB to use. I selected my own database not the sample database for OpenFire.
6. When I tried to reset the password for admin, I was presented with the following [OpenFire admin console (click to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkhyl.png) screen.

I can see changes in my database, but I'm still unable to log in.

I also tried modify the OfUser table directly, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

During the installation guide you must have setup your admin account to admin@XYZ and a password. Well at the time of the login use username as admin and password same as the one given at the time of installation.

Answer (score 0):

After fresh installation, start the openfire setup in "root/administrator" account. Select all the required features in the installation. Give the password in the 'account' section carefully. After setup, you will be able to login with username as 'admin' and your selected password.